# How to get react-joyride to work in a Next.js app?

Tags: next.js

I need to have multiple guided tours in the application using Next.js
I tried to have `react-joyride` in the parent component to show the guided tour.

It shows up for a second and then it scrolls down somewhere (not visible even if I scroll to the bottom).

I tried a few fixes like:
`body { min-height: 100%; }`
But it still does not work.

Here is the step config:

```
steps: [
    {
      target: document.getElementById('step-1'),
      content: 'This is my awesome feature!',
      title: 'This is my awesome feature!',
      // isFixed: true
      disableBeacon: true
    },
    {
      target: document.getElementById('step-2'),
      content: 'This another awesome feature!',
      title: 'This another awesome feature!',
      // isFixed: true
      disableBeacon: true
    },
    {
      target: document.getElementById('step-3'),
      content: 'This another awesome feature 3!',
      title: 'This another awesome feature 3!',
      // isFixed: true,
      disableBeacon: true
    }
]
```

And, this is how I call it in my component:

```
  <Joyride
    run={showTour}
    steps={steps}
    debug
    showProgress
    disableScrolling={false}
    disableScrollParentFix
    showSkipButton
    continuous
  />
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue right now, how did you solve your issue ?

Comment: Hi @NicolasMeienberger, I could not find a way to make it work in our application and switched to another library, namely Hopscotch by LinkedIn (here's the URL: http://linkedin.github.io/hopscotch/).
It turned out to be comparatively easier to implement and work as per our requirements.
Let me know if that helps. :)

Comment: Quick Update: The owner recently marked the library as unmaintained from now onwards. Here's the link to the repository (https://github.com/LinkedInAttic/hopscotch).

Answer (score 10):

For those with the `can't render div inside a div` error with Joyride & Next.js -- I fixed this by not server side rendering Joyride:

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const JoyRideNoSSR = dynamic(
  () => import('react-joyride'),
  { ssr: false }
)

const ExampleComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <JoyrideNoSSR
        steps={[{ target: '#first-step', content: 'Click it bud' }]}
      />
      <button id="first-step">
        Click me
      </button>
    </>
  )
}
```